# XSD - Input1 checked for an amount lower than 10% of Input2

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Input1 will be required and checked for an amount lower than 10% of the Input2.

Is it possible to do such a check in XSD in version 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible: cross-checking of rules applying to multiple fields requires XSD 1.1, or a separate "semantic" validator such as Schematron.